# Why expo-location getCurrentPositionAsync heading returns -1 on ios?

Tags: ios, react-native, gps, expo, location

The getCurrentPositionAsync function returns the speed and heading values ​​of -1. It says in the document that if location permissions are not open, it can return as -1, but the speed and heading return -1 even though my location permission is open. What is the reason? Thanks in advance.

```
const { status } = await Location.getForegroundPermissionsAsync();
const permission = await Location.getBackgroundPermissionsAsync();

if (status === "granted") { 
const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();
}
```

```
Object {
  "coords": Object {
    "accuracy": 13.815849315805039,
    "altitude": 108.1436996459961,
    "altitudeAccuracy": 14.495187759399414,
    "heading": -1,
    "latitude": 52.205276,
    "longitude": 0.119167,
    "speed": -1,
  },
  "timestamp": 1639056231575.1208,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Expo-Location)

Please Take Permission Before access location.

Below Snippet Code you can try..

```
    let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
  if (status == 'granted') {
   
    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
    console.log("Loc ",location);
    
  }
```